# Angular material 2 mat-error in child form not showing when submitting forum

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, angular-material2

Placing a child component with inputs in a parent form and submitting with invalidation will not show the errors in the child component only in the parent. The mat-error in the child will only show when clicked on the inputs.

To replicate the error  with this parent Form

```
  @Component({
      selector: 'lyx-parent-form',
      template: `
  <form novalidate autocomplete="off" role="form" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <mat-form-field>
     <input type="password" formControlName="currentPassword" matInput placeholder="current password">
     <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('currentPassword').hasError('required')">current required</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

    <lyx-child [form]="form"></lyx-child>

    <button type="submit">submit</button>
  </form>`
    })
    export class ParentFormComponent {
      form: FormGroup;
      constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.form = fb.group({'currentPassword': ['', [Validators.required]]});
      }  
      onSubmit() {}   
    }
```

The child component

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'lyx-child',
  template: `
  <div [formGroup]="form">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input type="password" formControlName="newPassword" matInput placeholder="password">
      <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('newPassword').hasError('required')">Password Required</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
   </div>  `
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() form: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const newPassword = new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required]));
    this.form.addControl('newPassword', newPassword);
  }
}
```

Comment: Found any solution to this problem?

Comment: No, I figured angular will fix it in one of their updates, till then I will use your workaround thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a workaround before I'm able to better understand the way the parent/child form interact.

When submitting the parent form manually set the child "newPassword" control as "touched"

```
onSubmit(): void {
  this.form.controls.newPassowrd.markAsTouched({onlySelf: true});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following solution that works for any number of nested forms. To use this directive, simply add `formSubmittedSync` to any child form group, e.g., `<div [formGroup]="childForm" formSubmittedSync>`

```
import { Directive, SkipSelf } from "@angular/core";
import { FormGroupDirective, ControlContainer } from "@angular/forms";

@Directive({
  selector: '[formSubmittedSync]'
})
export class FormSubmittedSyncDirective {
  constructor(
    @SkipSelf() private parentFormGroupDirective: FormGroupDirective,
    private formGroupDirective: FormGroupDirective) {
    this.parentFormGroupDirective.ngSubmit.asObservable().subscribe(() => {
      (this.formGroupDirective as any).submitted = true;
      this.formGroupDirective.ngSubmit.emit();
    });
  }
}
```